# System of DEs with constant term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

This is similar but not identical to standard examples in e.g. [Paul's Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx), and while the math seems straightforward the results I get disagree with what I get from numerical simulation.  Given a 2D system

$$x' = Ax + b$$

my solution is

$$x = c_1e^{\lambda_1t}\eta_1 + c_2e^{\lambda_2t}\eta_2 + A^{-1}b$$

where $\lambda_i$ and $\eta_i$ are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, respectively.  The first two terms in the RHS of the above are straight out of the textbook and indeed my simulation is fine when $b = 0$.  Is the $A^{-1}b$ term incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized any system with a constant can be transformed into one without by adding a dimension.  $A$ becomes

$$B = \begin{matrix}
a_{1,1}  & a_{1,2} &  b_0 \\
a_{2,1} &  a_{2,2} &  b_1 \\
0 &  0 &  0
\end{matrix}$$

and define $x^*$ so that

$$x^*_1(0) = x_1(0) \\
x^*_2(0) = x_2(0) \\
x^*_3(0) = 1$$

then the new system

$$ {x^*}' = Bx^* $$

has the standard solution.